# For loop in BASH here document

Tags: bash, loops

Hoping someone can help. I have a list of hosts in a file, what I want to do is grab the hostname and insert that into a template using a here document in BASH.

The hosts file looks like this:

*hosts.txt*

```
1.2.3.4 host1
5.6.7.8 host2
```

I then read this document with the following BASH:

```
while read LINE; do
  vmhost=$(echo "$LINE" | awk '{print $2}')
done < ./hosts.txt
```

What I am looking to do with this is take each host (host1, host2) and insert that into a document, as follows:

```
cat > ./file << EOF
[master1]
host1

[master2]
host2

EOF
```

If I put the here document into the while loop, it will write the last host in the loop under both master1 & master2.

```
cat > ./file << EOF

[master1]
host2

[master2]
host2

EOF
```

How can I ensure that when I'm writing the variables in the while loop I get a unique entry under each heading?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: just do it in `awk` ? Or is this a learning excercise (self-assigned possibly ;-) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `cat` and here docs:

```
nb=1
while read -r ip vmhost; do
    printf '[master%d]\n%s\n\n' "$((nb++))" "$vmhost"
done < ./hosts.txt > ./file
```